# Is it possible to create a new table from an unpivot results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unpivot

I would like to create a new table from the results the of an unpivot ,is possible to use the results from an unpivot to create a new table ?
Like for example can you add something like this `Insert into newtable`

```
Begin tRAN
select 2 AS Category_ID,
    Techcentre,
        kpi,
      Quarter,
      Result
From [Technology_Centre_New_Data_Import]
UNPIVOT
(
Result
for Quarter IN (Q1_15,Q2_15,Q3_15,Q4_15,Q1_16,Q2_16,Q3_16,Q4_16,Q1_17,Q2_17,Q3_17,Q4_17,Target_15,Target_16,Target_17)
)unpvt;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `select into`:

```
select 2 AS Category_ID, Techcentre, kpi, Quarter, Result
into newTable
From [Technology_Centre_New_Data_Import]
unpivot (Result for Quarter in (Q1_15, Q2_15, Q3_15, Q4_15, Q1_16, Q2_16, Q3_16, Q4_16, Q1_17, Q2_17, Q3_17, Q4_17, Target_15, Target_16, Target_17)
        ) unpvt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` syntax should work here:

```
INSERT INTO yourTable (co1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
SELECT 2 AS Category_ID, Techcentre, kpi, Quarter, Result
FROM [Technology_Centre_New_Data_Import]
UNPIVOT
(
    Result FOR Quarter IN (Q1_15,Q2_15,Q3_15,Q4_15,Q1_16,Q2_16,Q3_16,Q4_16,Q1_17,Q2_17,Q3_17,Q4_17,Target_15,Target_16,Target_17)
) unpvt;
```